# C# .NET Console app running locally & on Docker but crashes on Kubernetes

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes

I am facing an issue with a Console C#.NET app. It is running without an issue or any crash, and in Docker as well, running until stopped. On Kubernetes, it's not running successfully. It executes the code and crashes. I need the app to keep running on the Kubernetes cluster.

Can someone help me with this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You mention the app crashes. What is the error? Is there an exception stack?

Comment: Console app can't run on its own, not in Docker nor k8s. Docker containers can run long running services only. Console app executes and exits, and it makes the docker container stop (and this stops k8s pod)

Comment: @JuanR Hi, there is no error. It just says READY 0/1 STATUS CrashLoopBackOff

Comment: @Artur Do you suggest creating a Windows Service app instead?

Comment: It depends what the purpose of your console app. If, just for example, it downloads some files from some server, zips them, and uploads to AWS S3, and it should happen only once, then it's definitely a console app. To trigger this tool, you can use [Busybox](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox) image. But if it should perform this task by timer, for example, then create a background service. Use the `Worker` template in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Artur Thank you for this explanation. I am waiting for the information on how it should be triggered. I will update you here